# infinite loop recursively with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion

I want to loop through some functions recursively so that after last function again it goes to first one and it goes forever. Can anyone please help me out on that? I also want to know if there is proper tutorial or something that will help me out to solve these problem in node js looping and flow controlling. I tried online tutorial though But not able to understand properly.

```
var util = require('util');
var async = require('async');
var SensorTag = require('./index');
var USE_READ = true;

SensorTag.discover(function(sensorTag) {
  console.log('discovered: ' + sensorTag);

  sensorTag.on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log('disconnected!');
    process.exit(0);
  });

  async.series([
  /*func 1*/
      function(callback) {
        console.log('connectAndSetUp');
        sensorTag.connectAndSetUp(callback);
      },
  /*func 2*/
      function(callback) {
        console.log('readDeviceName');
        sensorTag.readDeviceName(function(error, deviceName) {
          console.log('\tdevice name = ' + deviceName);
          callback();
        });
      },
   /*func 3*/
      function(callback) {
        console.log('readSystemId');
        sensorTag.readSystemId(function(error, systemId) {
          console.log('\tsystem id = ' + systemId);
          callback();
        });
      }
  })

})
```

When I executed it goes func 1 -> func 2 -> func 3 and then hangs. I need to recursively loop these again and again.

Edit code :I TRIED TO LOOP SOME FUNCTIONS, not all

```
var util = require('util');
var async = require('async');
var SensorTag = require('./index');
var USE_READ = true;

SensorTag.discover(function(sensorTag) {
  console.log('discovered: ' + sensorTag);

  sensorTag.on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log('disconnected!');
    process.exit(0);
  });

//function loop(){
  async.series([
  /*func 1*/
      function(callback) {
        console.log('connectAndSetUp');
        sensorTag.connectAndSetUp(callback);
      },
      function loop(callback){
        /*func 2*/
      function(callback) {
        console.log('readDeviceName');
        sensorTag.readDeviceName(function(error, deviceName) {
          console.log('\tdevice name = ' + deviceName);
          callback();
        });
      },
   /*func 3*/
      function(callback) {
        console.log('readSystemId');
        sensorTag.readSystemId(function(error, systemId) {
          console.log('\tsystem id = ' + systemId);
          callback();
        });
      },
      function(callback){
        loop()
        callback()
      }

      }
/*
      function(callback) {
        console.log('readDeviceName');
        sensorTag.readDeviceName(function(error, deviceName) {
          console.log('\tdevice name = ' + deviceName);
          callback();
        });
      },

      function(callback) {
        console.log('readSystemId');
        sensorTag.readSystemId(function(error, systemId) {
          console.log('\tsystem id = ' + systemId);
          callback();
        });
      },*/
      /*func 4*/
      loop();

  ]);
}



})
```

Comment: Maybe those two links will help. Generators are a feature in Node >0.11 and IO.js. So maybe you read up on those. With this approach you'll avoid loads of callbacks or using the async library. Generators are exquisit when it comes to recursiveness IMHO
at 2ality: http://www.2ality.com/2015/03/no-promises.html
at strongloop: https://strongloop.com/strongblog/node-js-callback-hell-promises-generators/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [forever function from async](https://github.com/caolan/async#forever), and inside this call async.series

Comment: I used 
async.series([
    async.forever(
  /*func 1*/
/*func 2*/
);
]);
but it showed : );
 ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;

Comment: I think the correct use is: async.forever ( async.series([func1, func2, func3]))

Comment: But I wanted to execute specifically some functions, not LL , HENCE i WANTED TO KNOW IF POSSIBLE OR NOT.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
function loop(){
    async.series([
        //  your func here
    /*func 4*/
    , function(callback){
        loop()
        callback()
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

And then call it to start

```
loop();
```

**Another edit:**

Maybe there's no need for async at all

```
sensorTag.connectAndSetUp(readDevice);

function readDevice() {
   console.log('readDeviceName');
   sensorTag.readDeviceName(function(error, deviceName) {
       console.log('\tdevice name = ' + deviceName);
       readSystemId();
   });
}

function readSystemId() {
    console.log('readSystemId');
    sensorTag.readSystemId(function(error, systemId) {
        console.log('\tsystem id = ' + systemId);
        readDevice(); // start over again
    });
}
```

Comment: You need to call the loop() outside the function first to get it started

Comment: Can I do something like looping only specific function in same way?> then what I need to do?

Comment: What I mean is using loop under async.series to call some specific function again and again

Comment: Yes you can. Although im not sure what you mean exactly, anything is possible. Each loop can proccess different functions depending on an array you pass into async.series

Comment: See the edit. I wanted like 1st function under async.series executed once and I put rest functions in loop function as you suggested. I had edited the at later part, can you please look at that

Comment: It would now be easier to create loop with only func 2 and func 3 and one function for loop() in async.series and use it as callback for sensorTag.connectAndSetUp(loop)